# Android Google Drive API getRequest.getMediaHttpDownloader() is always null. Why?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm trying to update a progressBar by using a MediaHttpDownloaderProgressListener when I download a drive file but the following code returns me an NullPointer Exception:

```
  class CustomProgressListener implements MediaHttpDownloaderProgressListener {
    public void progressChanged(MediaHttpDownloader downloader) {
      switch (downloader.getDownloadState()) {
        case MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS:
          System.out.println(downloader.getProgress());
          break;
        case MEDIA_COMPLETE:
          System.out.println("Download is complete!");
      }
    }
  }

  OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/tmp/driveFile.jpg");

  DriveFiles.Get request = drive.files().get(fileId);
  request.getMediaHttpDownloader().setProgressListener(new CustomProgressListener());
  request.download(out);
```

The exception is always at this line:

```
request.getMediaHttpDownloader().setProgressListener(new CustomProgressListener());
```

because "request.getMediaHttpDownloader()" is null, BUT REQUEST IS OK (I TESTED IT).

Can you help me?

Comment: Hello @Meroelyth, I am trying to figure out the difference between: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/ and
http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/

For me seems the http client can be used on non google downloads. Your above example supports downloading chucks, which is a part of the api client library, not http. So I'm a bit confused.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Solved using this code:

```
private static void downloadFile(boolean useDirectDownload, File uploadedFile)
      throws IOException {
    // create parent directory (if necessary)
    java.io.File parentDir = new java.io.File(DIR_FOR_DOWNLOADS);
    if (!parentDir.exists() && !parentDir.mkdirs()) {
      throw new IOException("Unable to create parent directory");
    }
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new java.io.File(parentDir, uploadedFile.getTitle()));

    MediaHttpDownloader downloader =
        new MediaHttpDownloader(httpTransport, drive.getRequestFactory().getInitializer());
    downloader.setDirectDownloadEnabled(useDirectDownload);
    downloader.setProgressListener(new FileDownloadProgressListener());
    downloader.download(new GenericUrl(uploadedFile.getDownloadUrl()), out);
  }
```